# How do you sort the contents of a .txt file in numerical order?

Tags: python, sorting, numeric

I have some trouble making a code that arranges a .txt file in numerical order.

The problem I'm having is when ordering numbers `77, 45, 85, 100` in the .txt file it orders it as `100, 45, 77, 85`; 100 being the lowest.

Not sure how I would correct that as I want 100 to be the highest.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import operator


sample = open("score.txt")
csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=',')
sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for eachline in sort:
    print eachline
```

Comment: I think you need to convert the text to a float or integer. It's sorting in an unexpected manner because they are strings.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the csv file ?

Comment: You need to clarify a bit. Are you sorting a bunch of integers? Or is it things that look like this: bar3, bar15xyz, bar 32, foo1, foo2, foo10, foo23, foo103. If the latter, what you want is a natural order sort.

Comment: For a rant on natural order sort and a quick Python implementation, see: http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like budder says](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32833226#comment53502239_32833226), try to convert your elements to `int` or `float`. "It's sorting in an unexpected manner because they are strings." Assuming that you are working with integers you can change your `key` in  `sorted()` func:

```
sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort them numerically instead of alphabetically.

Try this:

```
sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda item: int(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The entries need to first be converted to integers to be correctly sorted.

**score.txt**

```
312
148
17
108
```

**python**

```
with open('score.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
numbers = [int(e.strip()) for e in lines]
numbers.sort()
print numbers

#[17, 108, 148, 312]
```