# How do I sort my text file if it has Integers and Strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm doing a high score system for my code for coursework, I managed to sort my numbers with some help from here, but now i decided to add the names so the high scores correlate to a person, it doeskin sort it, this is my code so far:

```
player1=input("input")
player1score=int(input("input"))


highscore = open("Scores.txt", "r")
whowon=("{0}-{1}".format(player1score,player1))
highscores = highscore.readlines()
highscore.close()
highscore = open("Scores.txt", "a")
highscore.write(whowon)
highscore.write("\n")
highscore.close()
highscore = open("Scores.txt", "r")
highscores = highscore.readlines()

highscores = [ x.rstrip() for x in highscores ]
highscores.sort(reverse=True, key=int)

top1=highscores[0]
top2=highscores[1]
top3=highscores[2]
top4=highscores[3]
top5=highscores[4]
top=("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n".format(top1, top2, top3, top4, top5))


highscore.close()

highscore=open("Scores.txt", "w")
highscore.write(top)
highscore.close()
```

the file outputs

```
68-Dylan
45-Snones
70-Pedro
```

Is there a way i can separate the integer values, sort them, then put them back together respectively?
The error code im getting for this is

```
highscores.sort(reverse=True, key=int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '68-Dylan'
```

Comment: Try this. Maybe this can solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833226/python-how-do-you-sort-the-contents-of-a-txt-file-in-numerical-order

Comment: I haven't tested your code locally in my editor but going through your code, I feel you can use a list of objects, each object carrying a score and name. You can sort this list against the score and basically output the score and name after sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say this is your input string. You can use `sorted`, which takes a `key` argument to transform the data prior to sorting:

```
l = '''68-Dylan
45-Snones
70-Pedro'''.splitlines()

sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-', 1)[0]))
# ['45-Snones', '68-Dylan', '70-Pedro']
```